# How to create box plots with all points where for each group, the color of the points can be assigned manually

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame:

```
> dput(df2)
structure(list(Genotype = c("miR-15/16 FL", "miR-15/16 FL", "miR-15/16 FL", 
"miR-15/16 FL", "miR-15/16 FL", "miR-15/16 cKO", "miR-15/16 cKO", 
"miR-15/16 cKO", "miR-15/16 cKO", "miR-15/16 cKO"),
`Cells/SC/Live/CD8—,, CD4+/Foxp3-,Median,<BV421-A>,CD127` = c(1191L, 1325L, 1089L, 1154L, 1147L, 1735L, 1441L, 1455L, 1560L, 1623L)),
.Names = c("Genotype", "Cells/SC/Live/CD8—,, CD4+/Foxp3-,Median,<BV421-A>,CD127"),
row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
MFI=c(1191,1325,1089,1154,1147,1735,1441,1455,1560,1623))
```

and I would like to make a boxplot with each point plotted for each group (miR-15/16 FL and miR-15/16 cKO) and have all the

```
'miR-15/16 FL'
```

points be closed black circles and all the

```
'miR-15/16 cKO'
```

points be open red circles. I would like to be able to manually adjust the colors and shapes/sizes of the points for each group.

So far, I have tried:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x = df2$Genotype, y = df2[2])) +
geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = .2), shape=1, size=5) +
ylim(0,max(df2[2])+10)
```

But I haven't been able to figure out how to adjust the colors/shapes independently for

```
'miR-15/16 FL'
```

and

```
'miR-15/16 cKO'
```

Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Balter beat me to the punch.... The only difference is that I set the color and shape parameters outside the ggplot call for future progamatic access.

```
library(ggplot2)

df2 <- data.frame(Genotype = c('WT','WT','WT','WT','WT',
                               'cKO','cKO','cKO','cKO','cKO'),
                  MFI=c(1191,1325,1089,1154,1147,1735,1441,1455,1560,1623))

color.groups <- c(WT="black", cKO="red")
shape.groups <- c(WT=20, cKO=21)

ggplot(data=df2, aes(x = df2$Genotype, y = df2$MFI)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = .2), size=5, 
             aes(color=Genotype, shape = Genotype)) +
  ylim(0,max(df2$MFI)+10) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=color.groups) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=shape.groups)
```

#### Update:

```
library(ggplot2)

df2 <- data.frame(Genotype = c('miR-15/16 WT','miR-15/16 WT','miR-15/16 WT','miR-15/16 WT','miR-15/16 WT',
                               'miR-15/16 cKO','miR-15/16 cKO','miR-15/16 cKO','miR-15/16 cKO','miR-15/16 cKO'),
                  MFI=c(1191,1325,1089,1154,1147,1735,1441,1455,1560,1623))

color.groups <- c(`miR-15/16 WT`="black", `miR-15/16 cKO`="red")
shape.groups <- c(`miR-15/16 WT`=20, `miR-15/16 cKO`=21)

ggplot(data=df2, aes(x = Genotype, y = MFI)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = .2), size=5, 
             aes(color=Genotype, shape = Genotype)) +
  ylim(0,max(df2$MFI)+10) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=color.groups) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=shape.groups)
```

[image]

### Update2:

```
df2 <- structure(list(Genotype = c("miR-15/16 FL", "miR-15/16 FL", "miR-15/16 FL", 
                                   "miR-15/16 FL", "miR-15/16 FL", "miR-15/16 cKO", "miR-15/16 cKO", 
                                   "miR-15/16 cKO", "miR-15/16 cKO", "miR-15/16 cKO"),
                      `Cells/SC/Live/CD8—,, CD4+/Foxp3-,Median,<BV421-A>,CD127` = c(1191L, 1325L, 1089L, 1154L, 1147L, 1735L, 1441L, 1455L, 1560L, 1623L)),
                 .Names = c("Genotype", "Cells/SC/Live/CD8—,, CD4+/Foxp3-,Median,<BV421-A>,CD127"),
                 row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
colnames(df2) <- c("Genotype", "MFI")

color.groups <- c("black","red")
names(color.groups) <- unique(df2$Genotype)
shape.groups <- c(20, 21)
names(shape.groups) <- unique(df2$Genotype)

ggplot(data=df2, aes(x = Genotype, y = MFI)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = .2), size=5, 
             aes(color=Genotype, shape = Genotype)) +
  ylim(0,max(df2$MFI)+10) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=color.groups) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=shape.groups)
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah this is good advice.  Useful if you're making a bunch of plots and you are tinkering with colors and shapes. Saves you a lot of time adjusting each plot as you can just adjust the variables and propagate the effects to all plots in one swoop.  Not to mention, it's easier to know which color you're adjusting.

Comment: Cool, I like the idea of setting the color and shape parameters outside the ggplot call. I am noticing strange behavior when I use the actual Genotype labels that I am working with: ('miR-15/16 WT' and 'miR-15/16 cKO'). I tried just replacing color.groups <- c(WT="black", cKO="red") with color.groups <- c('miR-15/16 WT'="black", 'miR-15/16 cKO'="red") but I get strange behavior where the color and shapes are not correct. the shapes become the letters 'b' and 'r' and the colors are cyan and blue...

Comment: please see my update. You need to put "mir-15/16 cKO" in backticks " ` "

Comment: @emilliman5 mine seemed to work with quotes in the named vector.  backticks worked too.   ggplot2 or R version maybe?

Comment: Please update your post with code and plot so we can see what's going on

Comment: Oh doh, nevermind.  For some reason I thought you had already quoted your named vector.  Yes when the 'space' is introduced in the names, you need to quote or backtick.  Sorry for the confusion.  Good answer!

Comment: Ok, so that works great with the data frame as created in the example but for some reason it fails with my imported data frame. I noticed that when I import, the Genotype column is read in as characters but when I create the data frame from scratch as in the above example, it is integers. Is there a different method to accommodate the character import?

Comment: @JohnGagnon, Do you get an error message? In what way does this fail? This code works just fine if Genotype is `character` or `factor`

Comment: @emilliman5 I get the WT samples looking like blue 'b's and the cKO samples looking like cyan 'r's

Comment: Here is the behavior when I ask for typeof() and call to the column (the data frame is called "iLN" instead of df2):  

 > typeof(iLN$Genotype)
[1] "character"
> iLN$Genotype
 [1] "miR-15/16 WT"  "miR-15/16 WT"  "miR-15/16 WT"  "miR-15/16 WT"  "miR-15/16 WT"  "miR-15/16 cKO"
 [7] "miR-15/16 cKO" "miR-15/16 cKO" "miR-15/16 cKO" "miR-15/16 cKO"

Comment: @JohnGagnon, please update your **original** post with the code you are using and `dput` for the data

Comment: @emilliman5, Thanks! I was trying to figure out how to dump all the information about the data frame and didn't know about dput(). I have updated the question with the dput() data.

Answer (score 3):

This may get you started:

```
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x = Genotype, y = MFI)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_jitter(aes(col = Genotype, shape = Genotype),position = position_jitter(width = .2), size=5) +
  ylim(0,max(df2$MFI)+10)+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(1,16))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'black'))
```

I've found this site very useful:
http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape